# How can I add an object to an object?

Tags: javascript, object

```
var fillets = {};

function fillet_change(thumb, cid, sku, width, selected_matte)
{
    switch(selected_matte)
    {
      case "fillet_matte_layer_bottom": 
        moulding_matte_canvas_width[i] = $("#opening_" + i).width();
        moulding_matte_canvas_height[i] = $("#opening_" + i).height();
        index = 2;
        break;

      case "fillet_matte_layer_middle": 
        moulding_matte_canvas_width[i] = $("#opening_" + i).width() + 10;
        moulding_matte_canvas_height[i] = $("#opening_" + i).height() + 10;
        index = 1;
        break;

      case "fillet_matte_layer_top": 
        if (mattes_default_selected == true)
        {
          moulding_matte_canvas_width[i] = $("#opening_" + i).width() + 22;
          moulding_matte_canvas_height[i] = $("#opening_" + i).height() + 22;
        }
        else
        {
          moulding_matte_canvas_width[i] = $("#opening_" + i).width();
          moulding_matte_canvas_height[i] = $("#opening_" + i).height();
        }
        index = 0;
        break;
    }

    var fillet = {
      index: index,
      imgsrc: thumb,
      width: width,
      cid: cid,
      sku: sku
    };
    fillets[index] = fillet;
}
```

However I am getting an error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '2' of undefined

So my question is how can I add the fillet object to another object or an array (doesn’t matter)?

Comment: Where does the value of "index" come from? How is the function called?

Comment: I don't see where `index` gets set.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: Index gets set above, depending on another value.

Comment: @AllisonC you need to provide the minimum amount of code to reproduce the problem. you have neglected to do that.

Comment: "Index gets set above, depending on another value." - where is the line then? I dont see it.. index: index, <---- where does the index come from?

Comment: I added the code that defines the index

Comment: Yea, deemn.. there is just too much wrong in this code. Accessing variables outside the scope of a function.. you got i, moulding_matte_canvas_height.. you got switch case which doesn't have default behavior.. etc. index is not defined within your code you posted. I dont see var index... if you defined index = 0; it just makes it as global variable. But only if some of those switch cases are actually triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Approach for adding as if you add in a queue.

```
var fruits = [{size: 3, color: 'yellow'}, {size: 5, color: 'green'}];
fruits.push({size:9, color: 'black'});
console.dir(fruits);
```

It must be Array[3].

0: Object
color: "yellow"
size: 3
**proto**: Object

1: Object
color: "green"
size: 5
**proto**: Object

2: Object
color: "black"
size: 9
**proto**: Object

Comment: I tried that and got: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Please open your console Ctrl + Shift + J under Chrome and write the 3 lines from above.

Comment: It doesn't necessary have to be an array, it can be array-like also `{3:"foo"}`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a index variable

```
function fillet_change(thumb, cid, sku, width, selected_matte)
{
    var index;

    switch(selected_matte)
```

Answer (score 0):

"Cannot set property '2' of undefined" means that you call `variable[2] = 'something';` and variable is undefined.

This may happen in that strings:
    moulding_matte_canvas_width[i] = $("#opening_" + i).width();
    moulding_matte_canvas_height[i] = $("#opening_" + i).height();

In your code I can't see where you define `moulding_matte_canvas_width, moulding_matte_canvas_height` variables. Are you sure that this variabels are defined and length of this array >= 3?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had fillets defined somewhere else. So I changed the name of the variable and it works:

var fillet_array = [];

```
function fillet_change(thumb, cid, sku, width, selected_matte)
{
  if (typeof(selected_matte) === "undefined")
  {
    selected_matte = fillet_selected_matte;
    //console.log("fillet_selected_matte: "+ fillet_selected_matte);
  }
  if (typeof(width) === "undefined")
  {
    width = .31;
  }
  if (mattes_selected_type == 15) //letter mattes
  {
    alert("Fillets can only be applied to rectangular openings. Your current layout does not contain any rectangular openings, fillet was not applied");
    return;
  }
  var img = new Image();
  img.src =  SITE_URL + '/system/components/compimg/' + thumb + '/pattern';
  img.onload = function() 
  {
    img.width = width * ppi; 
    img.height = width * ppi; 
    $( document ).ready(function() 
    {
      $("div[id^='opening_']").each(function(i) //for each div that has an id of opening_(number) 
      {
        //Set the values in the array with the width and height
        switch(selected_matte)
        {
          case "fillet_matte_layer_bottom": 
            moulding_matte_canvas_width[i] = $("#opening_" + i).width();
            moulding_matte_canvas_height[i] = $("#opening_" + i).height();
            index = 2;
            break;

          case "fillet_matte_layer_middle": 
            moulding_matte_canvas_width[i] = $("#opening_" + i).width() + 10;
            moulding_matte_canvas_height[i] = $("#opening_" + i).height() + 10;
            index = 1;
            break;

          case "fillet_matte_layer_top": 
            if (mattes_default_selected == true)
            {
              moulding_matte_canvas_width[i] = $("#opening_" + i).width() + 22;
              moulding_matte_canvas_height[i] = $("#opening_" + i).height() + 22;
            }
            else
            {
              moulding_matte_canvas_width[i] = $("#opening_" + i).width();
              moulding_matte_canvas_height[i] = $("#opening_" + i).height();
            }
            index = 0;
            break;
        }
        var fillet_xml = "<imgsrc>" + thumb + "</imgsrc><width>" + width + "</width><cid>" + cid + "</cid><sku>" + sku + "</sku>";
        var fillet = {
          index: index,
          imgsrc: thumb,
          width: width,
          cid: cid,
          sku: sku
        };
        fillet_array.push(fillet);
        mattes_mattes_xml = mattes_get_mattes_xml().replace("<fillet index='" + index + "'></fillet>", "<fillet index='" + index + "'>" + fillet_xml + "</fillet>");
        common_get_order_xml();
        moulding_draw(img, "fillet", selected_matte); //Call the moulding_draw function, which draws the fillet on the canvas
      });
    });
  };
}
```